# Is there a full list of hops all around the world?

Tags: hops

Is there a full list of hops all around the world?

Currently, I've been just collecting them as I drink and asking the brewers or the pub owners which hop the beer uses.

Wikipedia has a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hop_varieties but is there any other missing?

- Admiral
- Ahtanum
- Amarillo
- Apollo
- Bramling Cross
- Brewer's Gold
- Bullion
- Cascade
- Centennial
- Challenger
- Chinook
- Citra
- Cluster
- Columbus
- Crystal
- Eroica
- First Gold
- Feux-Coeur Francais
- Fuggle
- Galaxy
- Galena
- Glacier
- Goldings
- Green Bullet
- Greenburg
- Hallertau / Hallertauer Mittelfrüh
- Herald
- Herkules
- Hersbrucker
- Horizon
- Liberty
- Lublin
- Magnum
- Merkur
- Millennium
- Motueka
- Mosaic
- Mount Hood
- Mount Rainier
- Nelson Sauvin
- Newport
- Northdown
- Northern Brewer
- Nugget
- Opal
- Pacifica
- Pacific Gem
- Pacific Jade
- Palisade
- Perle
- Phoenix
- Pilgrim
- Pilot
- Pioneer
- Polnischer Lublin
- Pride of Ringwood
- Progress
- Riwaka
- Saaz
- Saaz Late
- Bor
- Premiant
- Rubin
- Agnus
- Vital
- Sladek
- Kazbek
- Bohemie
- Harmonie
- San Juan Ruby Red
- Santiam
- Saphir
- Satus
- Select
- Simcoe
- Smaragd
- Sorachi Ace
- Southern Cross
- Spalt
- Sterling
- Strisselspalt
- Styrian Aurora
- Styrian Bobek
- Styrian Goldings
- Styrian Celeia
- Summit
- Tardif de Bourgogne
- Target
- Taurus
- Tettnang
- Tomahawk
- Tomyski
- Tradition
- Ultra
- Vanguard
- Waimea
- Warrior
- Whitbread Golding Variety (WGV)
- Willamette
- Zeus

Comment: No list could ever be complete...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting a full list would always be tough as new varieties are being developed all the time. Looking at the above list I see a couple of varieties that have been out a couple of years that are missing (Mosaic for example).

Yakima Chief Hop Union has a pretty up to date list and since they deal in selling hops it probably would be a good source of the latest ones out there.

https://ychhops.com/varieties